# Vert.x Java Realtime Server Client communication

Tags: java, vert.x

I want to develop a client server application with the following needs:

- The server offers a small REST interface
- The server offers a websocket or something like that where

  - multiple users can subscribe to a topic and get events from the server.
  - the server should also be able to receive events back from the clients.

Most of this is kind of covered by the [Vert.x Real-time bidding example](http://vertx.io/blog/real-time-bidding-with-websockets-and-vert-x/). My only problem is that this example and all the others I found use a [SockJS handler](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs) and have a Javascript client. However, I have a Java client and want to do exactly the same (plus the talk back from client to server part).

Does anyone know a good example showing this use-case or can anyone write down a short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, you can start the [TCP event bus bridge](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge/java/) instead of the SockJS one. And to avoid creating your own TCP messages, have a look at this [TCP bridge Java Client](https://github.com/sebastienblanc/vertx-java-tcp-eventbus-bridge).

Comment: Is there a reason for not having an official Java client?

Comment: No, it's in the backlog, but no planned release yet

Comment: A client for various languages is currently developed by the vert.x team in this repository: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-eventbus-bridge-clients/